# can I merge OpenID connect/OAuth as one process for both Authentication and Authorization

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

Our application hosts both the user store and also the data for the users.  Per some customer's requirements, we are thinking to expose our application as the OpenID connect service provider to allow third party application to be authenticated by using our user store.  Our application would also allow third party application to access our data by using OAuth token as well.

It seems that we would need to prompt user twice to login and consent, once for authentication and once for authorization.  Can I merge them together as one? Or am I missing something here? I am new to this topic.

By the way, I didn't see a tag for "OpenID Connect".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the consent is given and how the authentication takes place - the OAuth 2 spec doesn't really say much about either of these. It will also depend on what flow you are using.

For a standard OAuth 2 authorization code flow, the user would normally be prompted to authenticate, and then prompted again to authorize the scopes that the client is requesting, so this would require two prompts anyway, even if you aren't using OpenID Connect. An OpenID Connect request is really very similar from an end user's perspective, except that the permissions the client requests also include access to their account information.

If a user has previously approved access for a client application, the system might store the approved scopes to avoid having to prompt the user in future.

I'd be wary of trying to implement both OAuth 2 and OpenID Connect from scratch as part of your development.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked long ago, but I'm answering this for future readers.

OpenID Connect subsumes OAuth 2.0. It adds authentication to OAuth 2.0's authorization.

When you get an authorization code and send it to the token endpoint, a successful response contains an OAuth-style access token (authorization), an OpenID Connect id token (authentication), and possibly a refresh token, like this:

#### Request

```
curl -s -u $client_id:$client_secret \
  --data grant_type=authorization_code \
  --data code=$auth_code \
  --data-urlencode redirect_uri=https://localhost/callback/ \
  https://openidserver.example.com/oauth/token
```

#### Response

```
{
  "access_token": "3Vx3oEq8m1GBTG8ZhISr**blahblah**5TqwcaCCq04",
  "refresh_token": "5azbf2c**blahblah**7t9sKW9dqf6poh0P",
  "id_token": "**redacted_header**.**redacted_id_token**.**redacted_signature**",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 300
}
```

So if you use OpenID Connect you are effectively using OAuth 2.0 as part of the overall flow.